# Computing effect size (partial eta squared) from a RM-ANOVA's F value

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, effect-size, statistical-power

I want to calculate the number of participants I need in order to get a power of 0.95, when replicating an effect. The effect size of this effect is not reported in the previous study, which is why I want to calculate it from the $F$ value and the degrees of freedom. The ANOVA is a repeated-measures within-group 2 x 2 ANOVA.

Is the following formula adequate to calculate partial $\eta^2$?

$$\eta^2_p = \frac{F \cdot df_{\text{effect}}}{F\cdot df_{\text{effect}}+df_{\text{error}}}$$

Comment: Repeated-measures ANOVA with only two conditions is just the paired t-test, right? Or are there any between-subject factors or perhaps other within-subject factors?

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question.